Flutter Xcode issue
From the last iOS update I have a problem with open my project in iPhone.
The issue is with
Xcode is taking longer than expected to start debugging the app. Ensure the project is opened in Xcode.
Error starting debug session in Xcode: Timed out waiting for CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR to update.
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008130-001E1C5E30C1401C.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on iPhone.

Each my project has this same problem with iOS.
Update all libs, update pods, flutter version, dart version. Flutter doctor perfect.
Xcode build:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code



My team and I discovered this issue with relation to the Firebase packages. For now, the recommended fix is to change the "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" setting in Xcode to "Yes". Please note, this approach may not solve your issue.

After researching and trying several solutions, I've compiled a list of steps that helped resolve the issue for me. Firstly try xcode->product->run and after that try in flutter. If you're experiencing the same problem, you might want to give these a try:

Clean the project and rebuild:

In terminal, navigate to your project directory
Run: flutter clean
Then: flutter pub get
Finally: flutter run


Delete derived data:

In Xcode, go to "Window" > "Projects"
Click on the arrow next to your project name
Click on "Delete..." next to "Derived Data"


Check Xcode command line tools:

Open terminal
Run: xcode-select --install


Verify Xcode and iOS deployment target:

Open your project in Xcode
Check that your Xcode version is compatible with your iOS deployment target


Update CocoaPods:

Run: sudo gem install cocoapods


Reinstall pods:

Navigate to ios folder in your project
Run: pod deintegrate
Then: pod install


Check for any conflicting dependencies:

Review your pubspec.yaml file for any potential conflicts


Increase build timeout:

Open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode
Go to "Product" > "Scheme" > "Edit Scheme"
Under "Run", increase the "Execution Timeout" value


Check iOS signing:

In Xcode, go to your target's "Signing & Capabilities" tab
Ensure your Apple ID is correctly set up and the provisioning profile is valid


Try running the app directly from Xcode:

Open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode
Select your device
Click "Run" button or press Cmd+R



These steps resolved the issue for me. Hopefully, they help you too!

appreciate it, it was the solution I was looking for.

an extra item from my debugging (I forgot to keep my flutter current): flutter upgrade
